# SQL Syntax Error - Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to run this SQL Query:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from voipwallboard_ast_queue_log where time = :time, callid = :callid, queuename = :queuename, agent = :agent, event = :event, arg1 = :arg1, arg2 = :arg2, arg3 = :arg3, queue_id = :queue_id ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':time' => $result["time"], 
        ':callid' => $result["callid"], 
        ':queuename' => $result["queuename"], 
        ':agent' => $result["agent"], 
        ':event' => $result["event"], 
        ':arg1' => $result["arg1"], 
        ':arg2' => $result["arg2"], 
        ':arg3' => $result["arg3"], 
        ':queue_id' => $result["queue_id"] ));
```

but i get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' queuename = '0899*400', agent = 'NONE', event = 'ENTERQUEUE', arg1 = '', arg2 =' at line 1' in /home/integra/public_html/callstats/copy/copy.php:57 Stack trace: #0 /home/integra/public_html/callstats/copy/copy.php(57): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/user/public_html/callstats/copy/copy.php on line 57
```

i cannot find what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `,` to join `WHERE` statements. You use `AND` or `OR`:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    voipwallboard_ast_queue_log 
WHERE
    time = :time
AND
    callid = :callid
AND
    queuename = :queuename
AND
    agent = :agent
AND
    event = :event
AND
    arg1 = :arg1
AND
    arg2 = :arg2
AND
    arg3 = :arg3
AND
    queue_id = :queue_id
```

Answer (score 0):

In a WHERE statement multiple conditions should be joined by an OR or AND operator

```
stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from voipwallboard_ast_queue_log 
            where time = :time AND callid AND .........
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. You need to specify how the items in the where clause work together - i.e. `AND` or `OR`.

```
SELECT * from voipwallboard_ast_queue_log 
where time = :time AND callid = :callid AND queuename = :queuename AND agent = :agent AND event = :event AND arg1 = :arg1 AND arg2 = :arg2 AND arg3 = :arg3 AND queue_id = :queue_id
```